# Is there any tool to automate Oracle Service Bus configuration for CICD and where to get it?

Tags: weblogic, wlst, oracle-service-bus, wli

I have tried WLST. I am able to deploy wars. I have seen that there is a library to access OSB:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/osb/java-api/toc.htm
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/osb/develop/GUID-AA6A4EAE-5F52-41B4-92A6-E0F3FACF5E2C.htm#OSBDV2771

I have read about WLI. In WLST console, I try the following:

```
wls:/osbdomain/serverConfig> from com.bea.wli.sb.management.configuration import SessionManagementMBean
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in ?
ImportError: no module named wli
```

I do not know if I have to download some JAR from anywhere or which install manual to follow.

Where is this JAR supposed to be? Where can it be downloaded?

Comment: This is the JAR that contains the package: com.bea.common.configfwk.ja_1.4.0.0.jar. It is installed with C:\oracle\Middleware

Comment: did you start wlst from this path ? ${FMW_HOME}/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh